# Limit user profile on specific OU using Group Policy

Tags: windows, group-policy

We have a host that will be used for creating VM clones from time to time for testing purposes.It is used actively for testing and users tend to keep a lot of files in their profiles.We would like to limit users profile size to avoid cloning unnecessary files to new VMs.
Is there way to impose limit on user profile on OU level without introducing roaming profiles?

Comment: What Windows OS would this be?  You could possibly just set disk quotas for the user profiles, but the method to do this can vary.

Comment: Sorry, this would be Windows 2k3 server.
I am not sure that 2k3 can have per directory quotas though

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a logoff script that deleted the usual locations where users store things in their profiles or on c:\temp or wherever. Just create a GPO, link it into the OU where the users live and create a WMI filter to apply it only to that machine (the VM). Then it only runs for users if they logoff from that machine.